# what is the rationale for using X.sort.(reverse=True) and not X.sort.reverse()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list called X that I want to sort alphabetically in descending order
and i want to know the rationale of "reverse = True"

```
X = ["hola", "como", "chao"]
X.sort(reverse=True)
print(X)
```

I would have written the following:

```
X = ["hola", "como", "chao"]
X.sort.reverse()
print(X)
```

But I see that it doesn't work and I want to know what it means to assign true to reverse

Comment: Probably performance. Sorting in reversed manner is just as complex as sorting itself. Sorting and then reversing is heavier by the reversing step. That being said, it doesn't matter unless you're sorting thousands of thousands of entries, but still nice to use what's faster if it doesn't come with readability cost.

Comment: @tkausl - my bad, but https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html still applies

Comment: `X.sort.reverse()` is nonsense - you aren't actually *calling* the `.sort()` method, you're trying to reverse the method itself.  If you really want to do the sort and reverse as separate steps, you have to write either `X.sort(); X.reverse()` or `X = sorted(X).reverse()`

Comment: @jasonharper: In a hypothetical language, `X.sort.reverse()` *could* make sense; Python, at least in the language spec, creates a bound method via the descriptor protocol when you do `X.sort`, and if you decided to hand-implement the descriptor so instead of returned what amounts to a plain callable, you returned an object pre-bound the notion of "this is a callable that can be called to sort, or you can access attributes of its own to produce a new callable with tweaked behavior", then `X.sort.reverse` could be implemented to produce something like `partial(X.sort, reverse=True)`.

Comment: But yeah, it would not match the style of the rest of Python, and all those custom descriptors and the objects they create would add *mountains* of code if you tried to allow all methods that currently use keyword arguments to tweak behavior to instead handle it with such chained method construction. Ain't nobody got time to multiply the per-method development/maintenance cost from "Define a simple C function, put a single line macro in the method declaration section" to "Write (at least) two new complete classes, one for descriptor, one for callable object" just for style points.

Comment: @jasonharper: Minor note: `X = sorted(X).reverse()` will not do what you want (because, like `list.sort`, `list.reverse` operates in-place and returns `None`). And `reversed` won't handle it either (because it returns a reversed iterator, not a reversed `list`). Closest you'd get as a one-liner if `sorted` didn't support `reverse=True` would be either `X = list(reversed(sorted(X)))` or `X = sorted(X)[::-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a rule on methods. Either:

1. They mutate in-place and return `None` (or something that is *not* the object it was called on), or
2. They leave the original object unchanged and returned a mutated copy

Mutating methods never return the original object largely as a stylistic choice by Guido van Rossum (the original creator of Python); if a mutated object is returned, he wanted there to be no confusion over whether it was the original object (mutated in-place) or new mutated copy. Doing many different things on a single line was also something he wanted to discourage; without `reverse=True`, the cleaner way to write it would be:

```
X.sort()
X.reverse()
```

as two lines each doing one unique thing.

That general rule is the case for *all* objects, not just `list`, but `list.sort`/`list.reverse` [explicitly document this rationale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> To remind users that [`list.sort`] operates by side effect, it does not return the sorted sequence (use `sorted()` to explicitly request a new sorted list instance).

For the specific case of `list.sort`, using `reverse=True` provides a couple benefits:

1. It avoids the need for a second pass over the `list` just to reverse the contents
2. For some sorting algorithms, you can optimize sorting for the case where the input is already mostly sorted (reducing theoretical `O(n log n)` performance to nearly `O(n)` performance in practice). If you are repeatedly adding new data to the end of the `list` and resorting it in reverse order, each new sort would see the existing sorted section of the data as being out of order, requiring a full `O(n log n)` re-sort, followed by reversing it again (to avoid the problem, each new re-sort would have to reverse the `list`, `sort`, then reverse again, adding complexity and overhead).
3. If you intended `X.sort.reverse()` to actually constructed a single combined reversed sort (not a sort followed by a reverse), so item #1 & #2 don't apply (no incremental cost for a final reversing pass), then you're introducing a whole new means of slightly tweaking a method's behavior, that would not be consistent with any existing methods, and would require *acres*  of additional code relative to just accepting the arguments to tweak behavior.

Admittedly, the Python standard sorting algorithm ([Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)) (in place by the time `reverse=True` was added), optimizes for runs of data sorted in either direction (forward or reverse), so repeated sort-then-reverse would still perform well, but even so, it's costly and pointless to rearrange all the elements of the input only to swap them back again at the end.

Sure, in a hypothetical design Python could have made bound `list.sort` methods a more complex object with methods of its own that tweaked the behavior, making `X.sort.reverse()` exactly equal to `X.sort(reverse=True)` (both would sort in reverse order directly without sorting in forward order, then reversing), but no other built-in type in Python does anything like that (bound methods can be called, and that's it, they don't provide extensible objects that can be tweaked). For that matter, I'm not aware of many other languages that allow anything similar (I wouldn't put it past some pure-functional languages, but Python is not pure-functional).

Supporting this would complicate a lot of stuff (e.g. you can't just have a common interface for methods, you have to custom-design the descriptors and the objects they return to make new objects with methods of their own; that's a *lot* of work relative to the existing CPython design that basically just requires a C function definition, plus a one-liner macro mapping the string `"sort"` to that function for the purposes of method lookup, with the process of creating bound methods handled by a single uniform code path for *every* C-implemented method) and would introduce questions about consistency (should you also allow `X.reverse.sort()` to mean the same thing as `X.sort.reverse()`? If not, why not?), violate expectations from tons of other methods which use keyword arguments to make slight tweaks in behavior, and not provide any meaningful benefit.

In a language without keyword arguments, sure, this might be useful (`mylist.sort(True)` or `mylist.sort(False, lambda x: x[0])` for forward order with a `key` would be ugly), but with keyword arguments, `X.sort(reverse=True)` is not meaningfully worse than `X.sort.reverse()`, and unlike the latter, it doesn't create confusion between bound methods and full-fledged objects with methods of their own.

---

As an historical note, prior to the introduction of TimSort in 2.3, Python used an unstable samplesort algorithm (with no optimizations for partially ordered data), and only supported a `cmp` argument (a function that accepted two values and returned a negative, `0`, or positive number to indicate if the first argument was less than, equal to, or greater than the second). It was only when 2.4 introduced the `key` argument (to allow Python to do the *far* more efficient decorate-sort-undecorate, aka [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) under the hood for you) that the `reverse` argument was added alongside.

When `cmp` was the only way to customize the comparison, you'd just write it to tweak the sort order yourself as needed, but with `key` functions, where you compute/extract new objects (typically simple built-ins like `int`, `str`, or `tuple`s thereof), you could only say what to compare on, not *how* to compare that data; it's fairly common to want to sort on the `key` in reverse order, and if that had required writing a `cmp` function as well, just to flip the sort order, it would have eliminated most of the benefits of `key` functions (specifically, that they are called *before* sorting exactly once per input, where `cmp` functions must be called, on average, `log n` times per element).

The newly stable sort also meant that, in the event you needed some comparisons to operate in reverse, and some in forward order (and you couldn't just invert values; `int` can be negated, but `str` cannot be), you could call `sort` repeatedly, from least important criteria to most, and the subsequent sorts will preserve the original order of elements that compare equal for that stage (and therefore the ordering imposed by the prior sorts). It's not great when you need to do this, but it's better than *also* having to add explicit `reverse` calls on top of all the multiple `sort` calls.

Comment: Some of this is wrong. The `reverse=True` doesn't make it *"sort in reverse order directly without sorting in forward order, then reversing"*. What it does is it reverses, then sorts in forward order, then reverses again. So `X.sort(); X.reverse()` is doing **less**, not more, and it isn't equivalent since that's not stable. [Link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58395759b04273edccf3d199606088e0703ae6b1/Objects/listobject.c#L2419).